# c++ multiple times memory allocation to the same pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory, allocation

I'm dealing with a piece of code, where I'm not 100% sure about its correctness. Please can you tell me that what do you think about it? (I'm coding in Qt)

Only a sample:

```
CustomWidget *widget; //defined as private

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), this, SLOT(onWidgetClose()));

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), this, SLOT(onWidgetClose()));

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), this, SLOT(onWidgetClose()));


void onWidgetClose(){
   CustomWidget *w = findClosedWidget();
   delete w;
}
```

Comment: There is a more appropriate place for code reviews - a different SO site called Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write your own `onWidgetClose` and `findClosedWidget`--particularly since writing a correct `findClosedWidget` would be pretty non-trivial.  Rather use the slot `QObject::deleteLater` which is designed for just this purpose:

```
CustomWidget *widget; //defined as private

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), widget, SLOT(deleteLater()));

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), widget, SLOT(deleteLater()));

widget = new CustomWidget(this);
connect(widget,SIGNAL(onCLose(), widget, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

Comment: thanks, yes in my real code I'm using deleteLater. What I'm mostly curious is the several times assignment of new CustomWidget to my private pointer. Is that clean and correct?

Comment: @MiroKarpis Yes, personally I don't like that style much either but I've been in situations (like this one) where it's just the easiest thing to do.  The fact is, this can't be all there is to your code right?  Each `widget` assignment has its own features.  So in fact I would give them each their own name and separate declaration.  Although what's written is perfectly legal, as long as calling code has access, i.e. is either a member function or a friend of the class that contains `widget`.

Comment: Or just widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);